# In Workshop: How can I create buttons (functions?) so that user can segment by day, week, month or year

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

*Background*
I've read about **Typescript**, but I am not a developer, so I am interested in how can I learn how can I create useful functions in Workshop.

*Question 1*
How can I create buttons (functions?) so that I can create buttons for users to select segment by day, week, month or year?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Functions to do that but you can also do it directly in workshop with a combination of button + tabbed section.

Indeed:

- you create a button (like a Menu button for instance) where you list all the options (Day, Week, Year).
- Then you create a tabbed section with as many tabs as they are choices
- For each tab you create the chart you want to show, segmented by either day / month / year etc
- You hide the header of the section (not to see the tab labels anymore)
- In the button, you add to every single choice an event "Switch to ... Tab X)

The downside of this is obviously that you'll need to maintain many charts and thus it is more painful if you have one thing to change on the chart (the color etc...) as you'll need to do it several times.

Hope it can help you if you want to explore non-technical ways of achieving the above.

Maxime